# How can I specify different level of multiple directories with uwsgi Emperor?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have multiple uwsgi.ini.

```
/etc/uwsgi/vassals/a/uwsgi_a.ini
/etc/uwsgi/vassals/b/hoge/uwsgi_b.ini
```

In this case, how can I specify multiple directories with Emperor?

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals(.*)
```

Comment: Like this? http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ImperialMonitors.html#glob-monitor-a-shell-pattern

Comment: "uwsgi --emperor /opt/apps/app*/app*.*" specifies files of the same hierarchy, how can I specify files of different hierarchies?